# Sum up ending with the current observation starting based on a criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, pipe, cumsum

I observe the number of purchases of (in the example below: 4) different customers on (five) different days. Now I want to create a new variable summing up the number of purchases of every single user during the last 20 purchases that have been made in total, across users.

Example data:

```
> da <- data.frame(customer_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),
+                  day = c("2016-04-11","2016-04-12","2016-04-13","2016-04-14","2016-04-15","2016-04-11","2016-04-12","2016-04-13","2016-04-14","2016-04-15","2016-04-11","2016-04-12","2016-04-13","2016-04-14","2016-04-15","2016-04-11","2016-04-12","2016-04-13","2016-04-14","2016-04-15"),
+                  n_purchase = c(5,2,8,0,3,2,0,3,4,0,2,4,5,1,0,2,3,5,0,3))
> da
   customer_id        day n_purchase
1            1 2016-04-11          5
2            1 2016-04-12          2
3            1 2016-04-13          8
4            1 2016-04-14          0
5            1 2016-04-15          3
6            2 2016-04-11          2
7            2 2016-04-12          0
8            2 2016-04-13          3
9            2 2016-04-14          4
10           2 2016-04-15          0
11           3 2016-04-11          2
12           3 2016-04-12          4
13           3 2016-04-13          5
14           3 2016-04-14          1
15           3 2016-04-15          0
16           4 2016-04-11          2
17           4 2016-04-12          3
18           4 2016-04-13          5
19           4 2016-04-14          0
20           4 2016-04-15          3
```

I need to know three things to construct my variable:
(1) What's the overall number of purchases on a day across users (day purchases)?
(2) What's the cumulative number of purchases across users starting from the first day (cumsum_day_purchases)?
(3) On which day did, originating from the current observation, the 20 immediately precending (across users) purchases start? This is where I have issues with coding such a variable.

```
> library(dplyr)
> da %>% 
+   group_by(day) %>% 
+   mutate(day_purchases = sum(n_purchase)) %>% 
+   group_by(customer_id) %>%
+   mutate(cumsum_day_purchases = cumsum(day_purchases))
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   customer_id [4]
   customer_id day        n_purchase day_purchases cumsum_day_purchases
         <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>         <dbl>                <dbl>
 1           1 2016-04-11          5            11                   11
 2           1 2016-04-12          2             9                   20
 3           1 2016-04-13          8            21                   41
 4           1 2016-04-14          0             5                   46
 5           1 2016-04-15          3             6                   52
 6           2 2016-04-11          2            11                   11
 7           2 2016-04-12          0             9                   20
 8           2 2016-04-13          3            21                   41
 9           2 2016-04-14          4             5                   46
10           2 2016-04-15          0             6                   52
11           3 2016-04-11          2            11                   11
12           3 2016-04-12          4             9                   20
13           3 2016-04-13          5            21                   41
14           3 2016-04-14          1             5                   46
15           3 2016-04-15          0             6                   52
16           4 2016-04-11          2            11                   11
17           4 2016-04-12          3             9                   20
18           4 2016-04-13          5            21                   41
19           4 2016-04-14          0             5                   46
20           4 2016-04-15          3             6                   52
```

I will now in the following dataset compute the variable I wish to have by hand.

- For all observations on day 2016-04-12 , I compute the cumulative sum
  of purchases of a specific customer by adding the number of purchases
  of the current day and the precending day, because in total all
  customers together made 20 purchases on the current day and the
  precending day.
- For day 2016-04-13, I only use the number of purchases of a user on
  this day, because there have been 21 (41-20) new purchases on the day itself

Resulting in the following output:

```
> da = da %>% ungroup() %>%
+   mutate(cumsum_last_20_purchases = c(5,5+2,8,0,0+3,2,2+0,3,4,4+0,2,2+4,5,1,1+0,2,2+3,5,0,0+3))
> da
# A tibble: 20 x 6
   customer_id day        n_purchase day_purchases cumsum_day_purchases cumsum_last_20_purchases
         <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>         <dbl>                <dbl>                    <dbl>
 1           1 2016-04-11          5            11                   11                        5
 2           1 2016-04-12          2             9                   20                        7
 3           1 2016-04-13          8            21                   41                        8
 4           1 2016-04-14          0             5                   46                        0
 5           1 2016-04-15          3             6                   52                        3
 6           2 2016-04-11          2            11                   11                        2
 7           2 2016-04-12          0             9                   20                        2
 8           2 2016-04-13          3            21                   41                        3
 9           2 2016-04-14          4             5                   46                        4
10           2 2016-04-15          0             6                   52                        4
11           3 2016-04-11          2            11                   11                        2
12           3 2016-04-12          4             9                   20                        6
13           3 2016-04-13          5            21                   41                        5
14           3 2016-04-14          1             5                   46                        1
15           3 2016-04-15          0             6                   52                        1
16           4 2016-04-11          2            11                   11                        2
17           4 2016-04-12          3             9                   20                        5
18           4 2016-04-13          5            21                   41                        5
19           4 2016-04-14          0             5                   46                        0
20           4 2016-04-15          3             6                   52                        3
```

Comment: Not clear about tthe expected.  Your code is giving the expected?

Comment: The last output includes the expected. I am looking for the variable "cumsum_last_20_purchases", which I just added by hand.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind that column?

Comment: I've added more information, I hope it helps to understand my goal. However, if not, I will take more time tomorrow to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a new grouping based on the last day the `day_purchase` columns is above 20, and then use `cumsum` on that:

```r
library(dplyr)

da %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  mutate(day_purchases = sum(n_purchase)) %>% 
  group_by(customer_id) %>% 
  mutate(above = with(rle(day_purchases >= 20), rep(1:length(lengths), lengths))) %>% 
  group_by(above, .add  =TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(cumsum_last_20_purchases = cumsum(n_purchase))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 6
#> # Groups:   customer_id, above [12]
#>    customer_id day        n_purchase day_purchases above cumsum_last_20_purchas…
#>          <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>         <dbl> <int>                   <dbl>
#>  1           1 2016-04-11          5            11     1                       5
#>  2           1 2016-04-12          2             9     1                       7
#>  3           1 2016-04-13          8            21     2                       8
#>  4           1 2016-04-14          0             5     3                       0
#>  5           1 2016-04-15          3             6     3                       3
#>  6           2 2016-04-11          2            11     1                       2
#>  7           2 2016-04-12          0             9     1                       2
#>  8           2 2016-04-13          3            21     2                       3
#>  9           2 2016-04-14          4             5     3                       4
#> 10           2 2016-04-15          0             6     3                       4
#> 11           3 2016-04-11          2            11     1                       2
#> 12           3 2016-04-12          4             9     1                       6
#> 13           3 2016-04-13          5            21     2                       5
#> 14           3 2016-04-14          1             5     3                       1
#> 15           3 2016-04-15          0             6     3                       1
#> 16           4 2016-04-11          2            11     1                       2
#> 17           4 2016-04-12          3             9     1                       5
#> 18           4 2016-04-13          5            21     2                       5
#> 19           4 2016-04-14          0             5     3                       0
#> 20           4 2016-04-15          3             6     3                       3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Great solution, thank you! Very happy that it became clear to you what I intended to do.